# How to manually set the scale for multiple boxplots in lattice bwplot?

Tags: r, lattice

I've got the results of clustering and decided to make a boxplot for each cluster, using lattice.
Next, I was faced with the need to establish a scale, acceptable to all cluster boxplots.

[image: First attempt]

Found a solution, which allows to exclude an outliers and set free relation.

```
library(lattice)
trellis.device(new=FALSE, col=FALSE)

bwplot(value ~ variable | Cluster, data = test, 
       layout = c(2,2), 
       prepanel = function(x, y) {
               bp <- boxplot(split(y, x), plot = FALSE)
               ylim <- range(bp$stats)
               list(ylim = ylim) },
       scales = list(y = list(relation = "free")),
       do.out = F)
```

So, I've got pretty good plots, but it can be better, if I manually set the ylim for each plot. Eg there is only integer values in my data and the value 0.5 at upper left cluster graph is meaningless.
[image: Second]

So, is there any way to set multiple ylims in bwplot parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation under `?bwplot`:

> `xlim` could also be a list, with as many components as the number of panels (recycled if necessary), with each component as described above. This is meaningful only when `scales$x$relation` is `"free"`, in which case these are treated as if they were the corresponding limit components returned by prepanel calculations.

The `ylim` argument has the corresponding functionality for the y-axis.

So, set `relation = "free"` in the `scales` argument as you did, and then pass a list to the `ylim` argument to individually set the y-axis limits for each panel:

```
bwplot(len ~ factor(dose) | supp, data = ToothGrowth,
    scales = list(relation = "free"),
    ylim = list(c(5, 31), c(0, 36)))
```

[image]